# why is facebook not using the og:title tag?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

its very frustrating

i have defined both tags, the default html one:

```
<title>Default title</title>
```

And aditionally, the opengraph one:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook custom title"/>
```

But facebook stills pulling the title from the regular title tag...

Can be seen/tested [here](http://goo.gl/AE2F5)

I don't think its a facebook caché issue because i first add the og tag and then tried to share it...

Any idea what am  I missing?

Comment: Try placing the fb metadata before any other header information (ie, directly under the head tag). When I [lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) your page I get warnings that your `og:title` property etc is not explicitly provided.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts (mine, too). but the tag seems allright, no?

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine to me when I check the source. Have you tried moving the metadata to the top of the head? I would also try just building a page with nothing but the needed facebook metadata and see what happens.

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fes.solmelia.com%2FnPromociones%2Fproducto%2FjanuarySupersale%2Fjsp%2FC_Home.jsp%3FstaticDomain%3Dfalse

Comment: "facebook stills pulling the title from the regular title tag..."

Comment: Ok so still a problem? i tought you solved it as you have marked one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: I meant it as in "what was the actual problem and how did you solve it" :) Someone finding this question in future will have no idea how it was solved.

Comment: Sorry i am spanish. I didn't think you where asking for the solution but for the problem! i did all this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8789859/533941 and also updated the regular title tag :(

Comment: Ok! weird as my test indicated that your HTML code was ok, but maybe it was a cache issue... hmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

debugger says your properties are inferred, that means that he was'n able to fetch them from your og metas. the reason for this may be invalid markup. try to place each of your og meta tags in different line and try to place a space before closing /> for valid XHTML

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Meliá - January Super Sales" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Meliá - January Super Sales" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Meliá - January Super Sales" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://d2p65vgzoeytng.cloudfront.net/nPromociones/producto/januarySupersale/img/icoPromoCompartirFacebook.gif" />
```

and etc.

i'm not sure, but this may work.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags seams correct to me and they work fine in the debugger if I dump the HTTP response from your server and give it as response to the debugger when I run a dummy web server with netcat.

But if you take a look what the [Facebook scraper get from your site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fes.solmelia.com%2FnPromociones%2Fproducto%2FjanuarySupersale%2Fjsp%2FC_Home.jsp%3FstaticDomain%3Dfalse) you see that the open graph meta tags are gone. If I do the same with the response from your site using a dummy web server they appear.

Do your site conditionally output the open graph meta tags somehow or are they always included?

What I did:

```
$ nc -l -p 8000 > fbrequest
```

Debug `http://myhost:8000` in Facebook debugger and dump request

```
$ vim fbrequest
```

Change request path to `/nPromociones/producto/januarySupersale/jsp/C_Home.jsp?staticDomain=false` and host header to `es.solmelia.com`

```
$ cat fbrequest | nc es.solmelia.com 80 > solmelia
```

Make fake Facebook scraper request and dump response

```
$ cat solmelia | nc -l -p 8000
```

Debug `http://myhost:8000` in Facebook debugger again and it will show that the meta tags appear and are correct.